# How to define priorities for request mappings in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Using SpringMVC, I have a method that catch all REST requests:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**")
public Object catchAll(@RequestBody(required = false) Object body, HttpMethod method, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // ...
}
```

Now I would like to catch just a few requests with the following endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object post(@RequestBody Object body, HttpMethod method, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // ...
}
```

Right now, when I call:

> /test

the second method is never called.

What can I do to have my 2nd method always called in place of the first one?

Comment: You should not have something that catch all request like method 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all as [Asura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2223111/asura) points out, do not implement a 'catchAll' method. Having said that, Spring MVC allows you to use regular expressions in URL(s).

Read the documentation for using regular expressions in Spring URL(s) [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex).

In your case, use a negative lookahead in your first URL to remove the ones that start with `/test`. That way your `/**` controller will catch all requests except the ones that start with `/test` and you can use your other controller to catch those.

Use negative lookahead in your first URL:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/^(?!test)")
public Object catchAll(@RequestBody(required = false) Object body, HttpMethod method, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
// ...
```

}

Now, this should catch `/test` requests:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object post(@RequestBody Object body, HttpMethod method, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
// ...
```

}

Comment: Could you elaborate on why a catch-all should be avoided?